# How to convert bytes to PNG image in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a image with bytes. Can you to tell how to convert into PNG. I have used
`echo -n '' | base64 -d >image.png`

Answer (score 1):

If you have .png image, you can make use of this tool to get base64 :-

```
https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-base64
```

or if you have bytes you can convert it to base64 from here :-

```
https://www.base64encode.org/
```

then run `echo -n '{base64}' | base64 -d > image.png`

replace {base64} with the result you got from encoder